# Configure SSH cipher on Cisco IOS 12.2(55)SE7

Tags: ssh, cisco-ios-12

Today a customer contacted me because he has upgraded his MacBook to MacOS X Sierra and since then, when trying to access a switch via SSH he got the message

> Unable to negotiate with 10.XX.XX.XX port 22: no matching key exchange
>   method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1

The switch is a `Cisco 2960S` running `IOS 12.2(55)SE7`  (C2960S-UNIVERSALK9-M)

I looked at the [command reference guide](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/lan/catalyst2960/software/release/12-2_55_se/command/reference/2960_cr.html) for this version,  but was unable to find any command to configure SSH ciphers. (we can only configure SSH version 1 / 2 or both)

Is it possible with this version?

P.S. Yes I'm aware that he should use RSA key authentication, and upgrade the IOS version, I recommended it but this will need some testing and change management.

Comment: Not sure you can fix this (other than upgrading the software), there's a workaround on the client side though: `ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 $HOST`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated by @Teun Vink in comment, no way to do so but the given workaround using

```
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-dss -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 $HOST
```

do the trick.